# Is "I think leaving for the USA when I'm 20" correct?

Tags: verbs, formal-language

I'm new here.
I was taking quizzes because I'm having an exam tomorrow and once in a while I find something I had no idea about, such as this specific case.
I thought that the only accepted forms were "To think OF + -ing" and "To think TO + infinitive" or maybe "to think (that) + -ing ...".

I had 5 options and I chose the "to leave" one but the program says that it's wrong and that I have to use "leaving" instead, without any "of" in front of it.
I've got suspect that this quiz program refers more to British English instead of the American one (just in case it might be useful).

Thank you in advance, this is a little bit confusing...

Comment: What is the exact sentence the quiz suggested? Or what were *all* the options?

Comment: Hi, the exact sentence is the one in the head of the question. All the options don't matter because the correct one, according to the program, is "leaving", while I chose "to leave"

Comment: I've never seen this usage of "to think" and I couldn't find anything so uhmm that's why I'm asking here

Comment: the "sentence" in the title is not a complete sentence. Is there more to the sentence? For example "I think leaving for the USA when I'm 20 would be a good idea" is perfectly valid and correct. For the record, "I think to leave for the USA when I'm 20" is not a grammatical sentence either.

Comment: I don't know why you seem so mad at me but that's the full sentence... I chose the answer which looked *least* wrong.

Comment: I'm not mad, just confused. No option you suggested would be valid there, so I'm assuming there is more to this question. If there isn't, then the answer is just that: None of the options you gave would make a valid sentence.

Comment: Okay, I only asked whether it was right or not... that's it. Normally, I'd have used "I'm planning [to + infinitive]/[on + -ing], but it's a standardized test and none of the other options were any close to what I thought. Since this quiz is made on purpose to trick people, I thought that the wrong one was *me*, like completely. Now I know that the mistake was the software's, thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no more to the question, neither "to leave" nor "leaving" would make a valid sentence in either British English or American English.

A valid phrase to fill in that blank would be "I will be leaving" or "I want to leave" or "I/he/she/they will leave/left/etc." Any of those would form a complete sentence.